Intermittent AP problems on Pi4
I am trying to setup a Pi 4 as a WiFi extender - something I can just plug in as needed to help with my internet connection. It sometimes works. Sometimes it works and then stops. Sometimes it fails to come up. I initially tried OpenWRT but was having problems with the RealTek wifi dongle. Then I tried with Bookworm - and it seemed to work right out of the box. Until it didn't. I'm now trying to troubleshoot further.
Hardware/software wise:

Pi4B - firmware version - Feb 29 2024 12:24:53 f4e2138c2adc8f3a92a3a65939e458f11d7298ba (clean) (release) (start)
Dongle: USB ID 0bda:0179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188ETV Wireless LAN 802.11n Network Adapter
Linux: raspberrypi 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.20-1+rpt1 (2024-03-07) aarch64 GNU/Linux

The RealTek adapter comes up as wlan1 and it is set to connect to my WiFi. It appears to work fine. I can ssh to the pi and then ping the internet (e.g. ping 8.8.8.8 works).
The built-in WiFi is intermittent as an AP. It seems like the bridging is what fails to work. It broadcasts its SSID and I can connect but sometimes I can't connect on to the internet through it. If I connect and log in via ssh, I can ping the internet (Note that if I specify ping -I wlan0 8.8.8.8 it fails [EDIT - this fails even when AP mode is working so it doesn't seem to be a useful test]).
I see some interesting entries in dmesg:
[  159.720421] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_vif_set_mgmt_ie: vndr ie set error : -52
I'm not sure if it is anything - but I do see this message repeat when I try to use nmcli to restart the connection (it still fails as an AP afterwards) - i.e.
sudo nmcli connection down <SSID>
then
sudo nmcli connection up <SSID>
[EDIT - I see these messages even when AP mode is working - so not useful for diagnosis. At this point I don't know if there is a command I can run on the PI that would tell me if the AP mode is functioning or not]
My AP profile (in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections) looks like:
[connection]
id=Test
uuid=f21dfc64-3fcb-42f4-93b1-############
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
interface-name=wlan0

[wifi]
mode=ap
ssid=Test

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=TestTest

[ipv4]
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=default
method=auto

[proxy]

Note I'm already using a crontab entry to delay the start of the AP mode on reboot in case that helps (which it appeared to) - it consists of the script:
#!/bin/sh
sleep 30
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/nmcli connection up Test

But as mentioned - it is just not a reliable AP.
Any pointers welcome - either get it up reliably or, failing that, something that lets me properly diagnose AP failure and restart it with some chance of recovery via a script (instead of powering the pi4 down and up again).
Thanks!
Markus

One thing (which may not have anything to do w/ your issue, but should be corrected): Do not use sudo in cron. If you need elevated privileges (which you do in this case), you should run your script from the root crontab; i.e. sudo crontab -e. Remove the sudo from your script.

It could be the rasp pi not having a few proper settings set.  Read https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-3-as-an-access-point/all.

Thanks. Still working on this -  there may be multiple issues.
Today it occurred and wlan1 (the connection to the internet) was down. I had to unplug/plug the USB dongle and it reconnected. I may be able to write a script for that scenario to automatically cycle USB power. Also - it may fail to reconnect to a weak connection (it's headless but I was testing a monitor and noticed it asked for the wifi password at one point).
These scenarios imply no internet on the pi while my question was about failing to share. My debugging may have been thrown off because ping on wlan0 doesn't work.
